# Double border around centered graphics

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, border

I need to center an image on the page and decorate it with a double border. What I have so far is two nested `fboxes`:

```
{
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{5px}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{3px}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{
        \fbox{
            {
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{3px}
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{1px}
                \fbox{
                    \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{test.png}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me two borders, but with messed up padding:

[image]

How can I fix the padding issue? Or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: this is not MWE, please post MWE @kontexify

Comment: The additional horizontal spaces are caused by line ends that become spaces. End the lines with the comment char `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minimal working example does what you want:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=3pt\relax
  \fbox{%
    \fboxsep=3pt\relax\fboxrule=1pt\relax
    \fbox{\includegraphics{example-image}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have several unprotected end-of-lines, that count as spaces:

```
{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{5px}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{3px}%
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{%
        \fbox{%
            {%
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{3px}%
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{1px}%
                \fbox{%
                    \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{test.png}%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
```

Here's an implementation that allows to specify separately the rule thickness and the separation. Inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` spaces and end-of-lines are ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\doublefbox}{ O{} m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { kontextify/doublefbox } { #1 }
  \kontextify_doublefbox:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { kontextify/doublefbox }
 {
  rule1 .dim_set:N = \l__kontextify_ruleone_dim,
  rule2 .dim_set:N = \l__kontextify_ruletwo_dim,
  sep1  .dim_set:N = \l__kontextify_sepone_dim,
  sep2  .dim_set:N = \l__kontextify_septwo_dim,
  rule1 .initial:n = \fboxrule,
  rule2 .initial:n = \fboxrule,
  sep1  .initial:n = \fboxsep,
  sep2  .initial:n = \fboxsep,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kontextify_doublefbox:n
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \fboxrule { \l__kontextify_ruleone_dim }
  \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep  { \l__kontextify_sepone_dim }
  \fbox
   {
    \dim_set:Nn \fboxrule { \l__kontextify_ruletwo_dim }
    \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep  { \l__kontextify_septwo_dim }
    \fbox
     {
      #1
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\doublefbox{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\bigskip

\doublefbox[rule1=1pt,sep1=3pt]{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\bigskip

\doublefbox[rule1=1pt,sep1=3pt,rule2=3pt,sep2=5pt]{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the examples, and the tip about end-of-lines. I do find @Skillmon's solution to be much neater though.